# awk command not outputting(awk: error cant open source file)

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Hey guys I'm trying to delete everything after the last `/` in a string (the parameter). I'm getting some issues that I can't quite figure out.. Sorry in advance for any stupid mistake I've made

```
 myvar1 = $(echo $1 | awk -f "/" '(print $NF)')
```

Sample input:

> ./root/desktop/test

Sample output:

> test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `-F`, not `-f` but there's other issues too. Change the whole line to:

```
myvar1=$(echo "$1" | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}')
```

IF you really want to use echo, awk and a pipe for this instead of just a bash builtin.

Also, the above selects whats after the last '/' not deletes everything after it so its not clear what you really want. Post some sample input and expected output if you can't figure it out from this:

```
$ x="a/b/c/d"; echo "${x##*/}"
d
$ x="a/b/c/d"; echo "${x%/*}"
a/b/c
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'm getting myvar1 : command not found.. Is that because of misplaced quotes?

Comment: idk, the command I posted would not produce that error message so I don't know what command you executed so its hard to guess what in that command could be producing that error message but if you left the spaces around the `=` like you had in your question then that would cause some kind of error so maybe that's it?

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution:

```
$ x=`basename /a/b/file`; echo $x
file
$ x=`dirname /a/b/file` ; echo $x
/a/b
```